# Unable to get C function return value from Lua function

Tags: c, lua

I tried to get the return value of C function through Lua library, but failed.
My code is as follows:

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static int testcmd(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_pushnumber(L, 0xBADF00D);
    return 1;
}

lua_State *initLua()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    lua_gc(L, LUA_GCSTOP, 0);
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L, "testcmd", testcmd);
    lua_gc(L, LUA_GCRESTART, 0);
    return L;
}

int main(void)
{
    lua_State *L = initLua();
    int error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, "testcmd()", 9, "line");
    if (error) { printf("Error @ luaL_loadbuffer()\n"); return 0; }
    lua_call(L, lua_gettop(L) - 1, LUA_MULTRET);
    if (lua_gettop(L) > 0) {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= lua_gettop(L); ++i) {
            printf("%d: %g\n", i, lua_isnumber(L, i) ? lua_tonumber(L, i) : 0.0);
        }
    } else {
        printf("No data in stack\n");
    }
    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to get 1 floating point value which is about `0xBADF00D` in `L` after `lua_call()`. However, the actual result is `No data in stack`.

How could I get the value pushed to stack in `testcmd()`?

Comment: You need `return testcmd()` as your chunk so that it returns the value instead of just throwing it away.

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't really get where I should `return testcmd()` to make `L` containing the value in the top of stack. I have `lua_pushnumber()`'ed in `testcmd()`. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Yes, that tells the C function to return the value but when you *call* the function from lua your statement is `testcmd()` which doesn't do anything with the return value so it doesn't get returned from the chunk. `return testcmd()` is the string you need to execute to do that. You aren't executing a direct call of `testcmd` there you are executing lua code that *calls* `testcmd`.

Comment: @EtanReisner It works. Please post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: This isn't close enough, unfortunately, but this is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850797/lua-executing-a-string-and-storing-the-output-of-the-command-in-a-variable/ (and I'm sure quite a number of other questions as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told the C function to return the value to lua when called (that's what pushing the value on the stack and returning 1 is doing).

What you haven't done is return that returned value from the lua chunk you are running.

When you call the function from lua (using `luaL_loadbuffer(L, "testcmd()", 9, "line");`) your statement to run is `testcmd()` which doesn't do anything with the return value so it doesn't get returned from that chunk.

`return testcmd()` is the code you need to run to do that.

Recall that with that `luaL_loadbuffer`/`lua_pcall` pair you aren't executing a direct call of `testcmd`. Rather, you are executing lua code that calls `testcmd`.