# Lua: returning or storing REPL/loadstring string output in a string variable

Tags: string, lua, read-eval-print-loop

The same question already asked here

[Lua: Executing a string and storing the output of the command in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850797/lua-executing-a-string-and-storing-the-output-of-the-command-in-a-variable)

But I want the function loadstring somehow return the result in string form that may be assigned to a string variable later to use further, what it returns is a function.
Below code is an example:

ret = assert(loadstring(str_cmd))()

ret is a function:(

How can I get the REPL/loadstring output in string form?

Comment: Provide a simple example of `str_cmd` and your expected result.

Comment: str_cmd = "print("A")"
output string will be = A,
It is all about output redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all output from `str_cmd` comes from calls to `print`, redefine `print` before loading `str_cmd` to save all output in a table. After running `str_cmd`, use the table in `table.concat` for instance.

Instead of redefining `print` you can provide an environment to run `str_cmd` in. You'll probably need to make that environment inherit from the global environment.